# How can I set a symlink from /tmp/mysql.sock?

Tags: mysql, symbolic-link

I've tried to set a symlink from

/tmp/mysql.sock -> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

however whenever I try to do it using the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I get the following response:

```
ln: failed to access ‘/tmp/mysql.sock’: Permission denied
```

I've attempted to use chmod but same response.

I need to do this because of an issue with HHVM https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4987

(I'm running Ubuntu 14.04LTS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the /tmp folder has the sticky bits set

This means your permission is denied due to protected_symlinks

When protected_symlinks is set to "0", the symlink following behaviour is unrestricted.

When set to "1" symlinks are permitted to be followed only when outside a sticky world-writable directory, or when the uid of the symlink and follower match, or when the directory owner matches the symlink's owner.

To change this behaviour

```
sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=0
```

Further reading [Permissions](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix1/FilePermissions.htm)

Comment: Ah thanks, that sorted it for me. I had to rename /tmp/mysql.sock and then create the symlink to the old name.